# The MDB drag and drop ui is not working for me?

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-ui-bootstrap

The MDB drag and drop ui is not working for me? I copied and pasted the markup for the MDB drag and drop from https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/jquery/file-upload/ into my code and this is what I got.

[image: My drag and drop]

instead of this

[image: MDB drag and drop]

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="file-upload-wrapper ml-2 mt-5 pt-2">
  <input type="file" id="input-file-now" class="file-upload" />
 </div>
```

Why is this? Every other UI markup I copy from MDB and use in my code seems to work except for this?

Comment: Did you purchase the plugin?

Comment: No, shouldn't it be free? usually the ones that need to be bought have the MDB Pro button on next to the copy code button.

Comment: I followed the link you provided and clicked the Getting Started tab as instructed and it says it must be purchased.

Comment: You added the angular tag but you're referring to the jquery mdb library. The plugin for angular is here https://mdbootstrap.com/plugins/angular/file-upload/